# Why drop down header menus in website using Bootstrap v2.3.2 aren't working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is the drop down menus aren't working. I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap v2.3.2 as the front-end framework. I have modified it with some open-source modals from the internet. Please check the long code below to see potential errors. I'm nearly cross-eyed looking for the error I made. Thanks for the generous help.

```
 <?php
include_once 'admin-class.php';
$admin = new itg_admin();
$admin->_authenticate();

mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","");
$con=mysql_select_db("rfiddb");
if (!$con)
{
die("Could not connect to database.".mysql_error());
}
//$studID=$_POST['studID'];


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>Courses</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/DT_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="vendors/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="vendors/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
    .well { background: #fff; text-align: center; }
    .modal { text-align: left; }
</style>    

</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">RFID Attendance Checking System</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="icon-user"></i> Pangalan <i class="caret"></i>

                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Settings <b class="caret"></b>

                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Tools <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>

                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Reports</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Logs</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Errors</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">SEO Settings</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Other Link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Other Link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Other Link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Content <i class="caret"></i>

                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Blog</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">News</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Custom Pages</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Calendar</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">FAQ</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Users <i class="caret"></i>

                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">User List</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Search</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Permissions</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3" id="sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav nav-collapse collapse">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="course.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Courses</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="cys.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Courses/Year/Section</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="sched.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Schedules per Section</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Records </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="subjsched.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Schedule Codes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="subjdesc.php"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> Subject Description</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-info pull-right">27</span> Clients</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-info pull-right">1,234</span> Users</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-info pull-right">2,221</span> Messages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-info pull-right">11</span> Reports</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-important pull-right">83</span> Errors</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="badge badge-warning pull-right">4,231</span> Logs</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/span-->
            <div class="span9" id="content">















                 <div class="row-fluid">
                    <!-- block -->
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">
                            <div class="muted pull-left">Records</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block-content collapse in">
                            <div class="span4">
                               <div class="table-toolbar">
                                  <div class="btn-group">
                                     <div id="thanks"><p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#form-content"><button class="btn btn-success">Add a New Course<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i></button/</a></p></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                     <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Tools <span class="caret"></span></button>
                                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Save as PDF</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Export to Excel</a></li>
                                     </ul>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                                <form action="nextupdateschedassigned.php" method="POST">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Course</th>
                                            <th>Delete</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <?php 
                                    $resulta = "SELECT Course FROM tblcourse";
                                    $get=mysql_query($resulta);
                                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get)){
                                    ?>

                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td class="center"><?php echo $row['Course'] ?></td>
                                        <?php $Course=$row['Course'];?>
                                        <td><?php echo "<a href='deletecourse.php?Course=$Course' class='btn btn-danger'> <i class='icon-remove icon-white'></i>Delete</a>" ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php }?>
                                    </tbody>

                                </table>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /block -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <footer>
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2014 <a href=http://www.cvsu-rosario.edu.ph/>Cavite State University Rosario Campus</a> • Created by Team RFID</a></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!--/.fluid-container-->

    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


    <script src="assets/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

    });
    </script>

    <!---MODAL-->

    <div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Add a New Course</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<form class="span5" id="form_sample_1" class="form-horizontal" action="addcourse.php" method="post">

                        <div class="alert alert-error hide">
                            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
                             You have some form errors. Please check below.
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-success hide">
                            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
                            Your form validation is successful!
                        </div>

 <div class="control-group">
 <label>Course <span class="required">*</span></label>
 <div class="controls">
 <input type="text" name="Course" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]*$" maxlength="10" value="" class="input-medium" required>
 </div>
 </div>


 Note: Please recheck details after filling in the data.


 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save" id="submit">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
 </div>

</form>
</div>

<!---MODAL-->




</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Is there a javascript error?

Comment: **Bootstrap 2 no longer supported try use bootstrap 3**. I see you have doubled up on some bootstrap js. It  I think because bootstrap 3 requires JS and Ajax to be at bottom of page above last `</body>` like the say on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ Make sure your locations are correct also. It is best any way to place all scripts at bottom of page makes load faster.